# YII2 Validation for several forms in one action

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Hellow i'm making several forms and their validation on YII with ajax and i have some problems

Here the view code:

```
<?
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'test-form',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
    ]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Имя"])->label('Имя'); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'lastname')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Фамилия"])->label('Фамилия'); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'country')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Страна"])->label('Страна'); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'pindex')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Индекс"])->label('Индекс'); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'card') ->textInput(['placeholder' => "Ваш номер карты xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx"])->label('Номер карты');?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'form_name')->hiddenInput(['value' => 'Form']) ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
    <?
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'mobile-form',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
    ]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model2, 'name')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Имя"])->label('Имя'); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model2, 'lastname')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Фамилия"])->label('Фамилия'); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model2, 'country')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Страна"])->label('Страна'); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model2, 'pindex')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Индекс"])->label('Индекс'); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model2, 'phone') ->textInput(['placeholder' => "Ваш телефон"])->label('Ваш телефон');?>
        <?= $form->field($model2, 'form_name')->hiddenInput(['value' => 'Mobile']) ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Then im sending data with ajax to controller, code:

```
 namespace app\controllers;
 use Yii;
 use yii\filters\AccessControl;
 use yii\web\Controller;
 use yii\web\Response;
 use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
 use app\models\MainForm;
 use app\models\EntryForm;
 use app\models\EntryMobile;

 class SiteController extends Controller
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */

public function actionEntry(){

    $model = new EntryForm;
    $model2 = new EntryMobile;

    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        $model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
       if($model->validate() || $model2->validate()){
           $json['ok'] = "";
       }else{
           $json['error'] = " ";                        
       }
       Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
       return $json;
   } else {
        return $this->render('entry', ['model' => $model,'model2' => $model2]);
   }
```

}

In models i have MainForm , and EntryForm and EntryMobile that extends MainForm with their own rules.

Here is a question: 
How to make $model->validation() and $model2->validation() in one method? Or how to make the controller method width on model for two forms. Scenarios doesnt work cause they made me make the same. Two object and etc. Please help

Comment: Though I answered already, I have a question. Why not using only one form with two fieldsets (one for each model)?

Comment: your actual question is really hard to understand please add all 3 models or add a link to the pastebin, what i get is that you are trying to call the validate in one go for both of the models.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **bitwise** `and` for testing both models validations. Like:

```
$model->validate() & $model2->validate()
```

Which will then proceed only if both conditions are true but will test both of them anyway (which should throw the validation errors you expect to see).